# Creating a new column that is an average of non-adjacent rows in the data frame

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I have multiple columns of variables relating to different question responses on a questionnaire. I wish to generate a new column in the data frame that is an average of a set of these preceding variables. I have seen that rowMeans can be used for this, but this seems to only work for adjacent columns, but the columns I want to average are not adjacent. I also want some control over how missing data is dealt with. I created example data using

```
Var1<- c(1.5, 2.3, NA, NA, 2.3, 3.3)
Var2<- c(1.7, 2.2, 4.7, 13.3, 1.7, 1.5)
Var3<- c(5.1, 6.7, 3.4, 5.5, NA, 8.7)
Var4<- c(4.5, 5.4, NA, 4.5, 5.4, 8.9)
```

Which gives

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1  1.5  1.7  5.1  4.5
2  2.3  2.2  6.7  5.4
3  NA   4.7  3.4  NA
4  NA   13.3  5.5  4.5
5  2.3  1.7  NA  5.4
6  3.3  1.5  8.7  8.9
```

So I want to create a new column or variable in this data frame that is an average of Var1, Var2 and Var4 (but not Var3). I also want it to still produce an average of remaining data if data for one of the variables is missing, but I want it to return NA in the new column if there is missing data for two of the columns. So for person 3 the new column would be NA, but for person 4 and 5 an average of the available values in the three columns would be produced.

I hope this makes sense, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to check the number of `NA`s for the selected columns by subsetting the dataset.  If it is greater than 1, then return NA or else 1.  Then, with `rowMeans` get the `mean` of the rows for the selected columns and change those rows that have more than 1 NA to NA

```
# column index 
ind <- c(1, 2, 4)    
i1 <- NA^(rowSums(is.na(df1[ind])) > 1)
df1$newCol <- rowMeans(df1[ind], na.rm = TRUE) * i1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given..

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
```

One line solution would be..

```
df1$newCol <- apply(df1[,-3],1,function(x){ifelse(sum(is.na(x))>1,NA,mean(x,na.rm=T))})
```